# Command 'lualatex -interaction=batchmode texput.tex' returned non-zero exit status 127 after rendering a pdf using latex in Django

Tags: django, django-views, latex, pdflatex, django-settings

Hi i want to render a pdf using latex, but there was an error displayed during generate the pdf after pressing a button(for save and generate a pdf latex in same time):

this is the error:

```
Command 'lualatex -interaction=batchmode  texput.tex' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

this my **views.py:**

```
@login_required
def forms_render_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
   if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ReportForm(request.POST, )
         form.instance.user=request.user
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            obj_Formulaire = Loads.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
            field_obj_load_between_posts = Loads._meta.get_field('load_between_posts')
            field_value_load_between_posts = field_obj_load_between_posts.value_from_object(obj_Formulaire)  
            load_between_posts = field_value_load_between_posts
            if load_between_posts == True:
                field_obj_custom_load = Loads._meta.get_field('custom_load')
                field_value_custom_load = field_obj_custom_load.value_from_object(obj_Formulaire)  
                qh = float(field_value_custom_load)
            else:
                qh = float(0)
            context = { 
                    'qh': qh,
                }
            template_name = 'pages/test.tex'
            context = {'qh': qh}
            return render_to_pdf(request, template_name, context, filename='test.pdf')
   form = ReportForm()
   context = {'form': form}
   return render(request, 'pages/form_gelander_report.html',  context)
```

this is my **settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   'NAME': 'tex',
  }

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_tex',
]
```

traceback of the error:

```
in django_tex/core.py, line 37, in run_tex_in_directory
            stderr=PIPE,
            check=True,
            cwd=directory,
        )
    except CalledProcessError as called_process_error:
        try:
            with open(
                os.path.join(directory, "texput.log"), "r", encoding="utf-8" …
            ) as f:
                log = f.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            raise called_process_error
        else:
            raise TexError(log=log, source=source, template_name=template_name)
```

PS : i have installed the library django_tex using:

```
pip install django_tex
```

Answer (score -1):

I had been facing with same issue , try installing `texlive-latex-base`
It worked for me and passed this error